# Inside a shell script, what is the purpose of reading from STDERR?

Tags: shell, unix

I found the following line inside `update-grub-legacy-ec2`:

```
echo -n "Would you like $menu_file generated for you? " >&2
echo -n "(y/N) " >&2
read answer <&2
```

Is there any reason to read from 2 instead of 0?

(`update-grub-legacy-ec2` is [on GitHub](https://github.com/racker/cloud-init-debian-pkg/blob/master/debian/update-grub-legacy-ec2#L1098).)

Comment: It does make it impossible to do `yes | update-grub-legacy-ec2`.

Comment: You can do `update-grub-legacy-ec2 2< <(yes)` (in `bash`) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, there has to be some sort of preparation of the file descriptors before this code is called.

File descriptor 2, in this example, is being used bi-directionally, and is not therefore the usual output to a (p)tty, or a pipe that has been joined to another process.

Therefore, I would predict, that there is some preparation code that sets file descriptor 2 to be some sort of socket connected to another process.

Comment: I checked, and couldn't find any I/O preparation for `2`. You can find the source here: https://github.com/racker/cloud-init-debian-pkg/blob/master/debian/update-grub-legacy-ec2#L1098